# Add "Conflicted Edit" to Edit Stats

Tags: feature-request, rejected-edits

My Edit stats as seen in [edit histories](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7809132) are as follows.

> krisdestruction had 77 edit suggestions approved, and 18 edit suggestions rejected

However most of my rejected edits are due to conflicted edits, which misrepresents rejected edits that are actually due to my error. Can a third category be added to separate/indicate "Conflicted Edits"?

Comment: Or just remove conflicted edits from the rejected edits count

Comment: @grgarside well technically a conflicted edit is a rejected edit, but that works too!